# wpf application not loading image in windows 10 while in windows 7 it works

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, windows-10

We have a wpf application that runs on windows 7 and windows 10, on pc and tablet.

we have a window that we use it as splash screen, and when trying to open it during the application in windows 7 it shows the image and in windows it shows the the blank window.

We tried to load the image as static resource, open the splash screen in another thread, use 7KB images instead of 1MB, but it still not works.

We tried to open the splash at the start of the application and it works.

We tried to open new project with the 1MB images and it works, so i don't know what's happing during the run of the application that prevent it from loading the image in windows 10.

the splash screen .xaml code:

```
<Window .... WindowState="Maximized" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" Height="1080" Width="1980">
  <Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="LoadingDrill" UriSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Splash.png"/>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid x:Name="me">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource LoadingDrill}"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

the .cs code:

```
    private static SplashViewer singleton;

    public static void CloseSplash()
    {
        if (singleton != null)
        {
            singleton.Close();
            singleton = null;
        }
    }

    public static void ShowSplash()
    {
        if (singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new SplashViewer();
            singleton.Closed += Singleton_Closed;
            singleton.Show();
        }
    }

    private static void Singleton_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        singleton = null;
    }

    public SplashViewer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        me.DataContext = this;
    }
```

open the splash screen:

```
SplashViewer.ShowSplash();
///
///do something...
///
SplashViewer.CloseSplash();
```

another try:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { SplashViewer.ShowSplash(); }));
```

anyone as an idea what to do with it?

Comment: Is the Build Action of the image file set to Resource?

Comment: yes. we also tried to set as content and copy to output dir

Comment: we tried it... while running the app in windows 10 it works at the startup of the application, but during the application run, when we try to call this window it doesnt load the image.

Comment: You should probably show us the code where you create and show that splash screen.

Comment: code has been added

Comment: You might consider using ILSpy to verify the file details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We end up using DevExpress DXSplashScreen, it works.

If someone know's why it doesn't work with regular window we'll be glad to know too..